# Inductive coupling using earth ground instead of negative terminal in a power supply

Tags: power-supply, ground, inductance

I was a TA for an introductory EE class when I heard this comment. We would help students through basic lab exercises. Helping them troubleshoot, the students would sometimes use the ground connection instead of the negative terminal of the power supply when using it as a voltage source.

[image]

I would tell them you shouldn’t do this because the power supply is regulating the voltage across the + and - terminals, and not across + and earth ground, and left it at that (hard to expect much insight from an undergrad TA). Once, when the professor introduced the equipment to the students, they were explaining that you should use the negative terminal and not the earth ground terminal because “connecting to earth ground will introduce inductive coupling to the circuit.” It was the first week of the intro course, so no one really understood the prof’s point or inquired further.

Why does this happen exactly? I am thinking that the loop area of the entire circuit increases when the return connects to earth ground and creates a significant inductance throughout the circuit path. Is this the idea? Is there more to it?

Comment: You'll get earth fault currents causing noise and even device failures but, without doubt that isn't an inductive coupling effect .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there would be any inductive coupling. Professors can make mistakes too, maybe someone has given the same explanation to professor at start of studies so  the same mistake just gets passed on.

The earth socket is just connected to mains earth that comes in to the power supply via the power cord.

The blue and red sockets are the negative and positive terminals of the isolated and thus floating output voltage, which has no conductive path to earth.

It would simply not complete a circuit so the powered circuit would not work if connected between red and green terminals.

Sometimes there is a removable link between green and blue terminals. If it is present it can cause ground loops. If the device that is powered by the power supply is also connected to something else, like a desktop computer which has it's common ground connected to earth too, then it will complete a circuit via the building mains earth wiring inside the walls.

So by not using the green terminal on a power supply at all, it allows the powered circuit to float, so that it can be safely connected to other devices without ground loops.

Comment: I don't get how a grounded portable device in the circuit would help completing the circuit from + to Earth on the isolated power supply. Could you please expand this idea ?

Comment: @tobalt I forgot to mention that it applies when the lab supply has a connection between earth and negative terminals. Sometimes there is a removable bar between terminals, or a user made connection with wires.

Comment: Ok but then the current would anyway directly return to the negative port and not flow in/out the earth terminal. And without this bar, I just see no way how the circuit can be closed at all, regardless of what else is connected between + and earth by other devices.

Comment: Without the bar, the circuit does not complete. I had that in my answer. I simply forgot to paste the part about the earth link bar before I explained how the current might flow when the bar is present.

Comment: Thanks understood :)